# Why does JavaScript setDate not return a date?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I created a custom calendar for my application. I am using `new Date()` to set the state.

```
const [activeDate, setActiveDate] = useState(new Date())
```

When I console log activeDate this what I get back:

```
Sun Aug 16 2020 19:33:22 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

When I apply the setDate() method `activeDate.setDate(4)` this is what is returned

```
1596677602918
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is the timestamp.

First understand how that hook syntax work.

In your case `activeDate` is a variable and `setActiveDate` is a method to update that variable. If you want to update `activeDate` to 4, you should use `setActiveDate(4)`. It will update the value of `activeDate`.

Comment: setActiveDate((date) => {
      if (!item.match && item !== -1) {
        console.log('Date: ', date)
        console.log('Update date: ', date.subtract(1, 'day'))
        return date.set('date', item)
      }
    });

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for the help